# How to override new Dom element in Vue js template?

Tags: javascript, dom, vuejs2

I have method **getDataA** where I am doing some calculation after getting this data.and It is update when I pass  kdata using bus event.

```js
getDataA: function (kdata) {

  var doingcalculation = kdata;
  this.showSideBarGraph(doingcalculation);

}
```

```js
  mounted: function () {
      bus.$on('updated', this.getDataA);
    }
```

So, first time it's working but when I pass a event on that  **getDataA** it creates a new graph using new data!

[image]

Here is my **showSideBarGraph** which one is creating graph.

```js
showSideBarGraph: function (mresult) {

      var totaldata = mresult;

      var perfbud =[[
                    {"value": self.g1total,
                      "color": "#6aae6a"},
                    {"value": self.g1col2,
                      "color": "#356307"},
                    { "value": self.g1col1,
                      "color": "#005128"}
                  ],
                  [
                    {"value": self.g2total,
                      "color": "#6aae6a"},
                    {"value": self.g2col2 ,
                      "color": "#356307"},
                    { "value": self.g2col1,
                      "color": "#005128"}
                  ]
                ];


        new RadialProgressChart(".graph", {
        stroke: {
        width: 24,
        gap: 14
        },
        animation: {
        duration: -1,
        delay: -1
        },
        series: perfbud[0]
        });

        /////////
        new RadialProgressChart('.graph2', {
        // diameter: 42,
        stroke: {
        width: 24,
        gap: 14
        },
        animation: {
        duration: -1,
        delay: -1
        },
        // data is now from Vue object

        series:perfbud[1]
        }
        )

        ////// Linear Bar


        var umsatz=[{
          "name": "Jan",
          "value": um1},{
          "name": "Feb",
          "value": um2},{
          "name": "Tot",
          "value": um3}];


        var title = "Umsatz";

        var colorPicker = ["#000000", "#356307", "#00783b", "#008c45", "#009f4f", "#6aae6a"];

        var dataset =umsatz;
        var max = d3.max(dataset, function(d){ return d.value; });
        var currency = "CHF";
        var dest = "#rightLowerGraph";

        // add the title
        var h4 = document.createElement('h4');
        h4.innerText = title;
        document.querySelector(dest).append(h4);

        // Loop through the elements and render those
        for(var i = 0, ln = dataset.length; i < ln; i++) {
        // Captions first
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.className = "col-xs-12";
        // left part
        var left = document.createElement("span");
        left.innerText = dataset[i].name+":";
        div.append(left);
        // right part
        var pickedColor = colorPicker[Math.round((dataset[i].value/max)*(colorPicker.length-1))];
        var right = document.createElement("span");
        right.style.float = "right";
        right.innerHTML = currency + " " + "<span style='color:"+pickedColor+"'>"+dataset[i].value+"</span>";
        div.append(right);
        // append
        document.querySelector(dest).append(div);
        // Make an SVG Container
        var svg = d3.select(dest).append("svg")
                                            .attr("width", "100%")
                                            .attr("height", 22);
        // Draw the Rectangle
        var rectangle = svg.append("rect")
                                    .attr("x", 0)
                                    .attr("y", 0)
                                    .attr("rx", 10)
                                    .attr("ry", 30)
                                    .attr("width", (100*dataset[i].value/max)+"%")
                                    .attr("height", 22)
                                    .attr("fill", pickedColor);
        //
        document.querySelector(dest).append(document.createElement("br"));


        }


  }
```

**perfbud** is the object data for 2 Radical graphs.

**umsatz**  is the object data from 1 linear chart.

Actuallty when I pass data 2nd time It creates 4 Radical and 2 linear chart.
and for 3rd times 6 and 3.

**UPDATED:**
Here is my solution till now. But problem is that it is not showing initially. May be I didn't update it. when i refresh that component that time it is showing.

What I missed on watch option ? and How I can organize it now ?
BTW, I am getting update value in template as well .

```js
<script>
import {bus} from '../bus'
export default {

  props:['values'],
  name: 'perf-graph',
  data () {
    return {
      title: 'PerfChart',
      radical1:'',
      perfbud: this.values,
      ggg:'',t:''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    buildOptions:function(up){
      var res = up;
      console.log('response');


  }
},
    created: function () {
    this.buildOptions();
    },
  mounted: function () {
    // bus.$on('lastdata',this.buildOptions);
console.log(this.value);
console.log('from perf',this.perfbud[0]);
    this.radical1 = new RadialProgressChart(this.$el, {
      diameter: 42,
      stroke: {
      width: 24,
      gap: 14
      },
      animation: {
      duration: -1,
      delay: -1
      },
      series:this.value[0]
  });

    },
  watch:{
  values:function(nv){
      // console.log('test', this.buildOptions);
    // this.radical1.update(nv);
  }
}
}
</script>
```

```html
<template id="perf-graph">
  <div>{{values}}</div>

</template>
```

and the Libraries what we need 
https://github.com/pablomolnar/radial-progress-chart
I am following this project.

Comment: Nothing to do with Vue, really, you just need to generalize your `showSideBarGraph` function to accept a destination as argument instead of hard coding `"rightLowerGraph` as `dest`. Then replace the content of the `dest` with new markup you build instead of appending to it.

Comment: Can you show me an example  It would be great for me.

Comment: For that, You'll need to provide us with a [minimal but compete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) version fo your code.

Comment: Updated the project. Please, Tell me what you need.

Comment: You should *not* set chart instance on data, it will make it reactive and vue will mess it up.

Comment: Also, Your template should be an empty div, why are you displaying raw values there?

Comment: I just tried to check the values whether changing or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a reusable component for the graph plugin you use. An example of such an approach is given below, keep in mind, this code is just a starting point for you to build upon and hence is not perfect but works.

**Vue component:**

```
var radialGraph=Vue.component("radial-graph",{
    props:["settings","values"],
  template:"#radial-graph",
    mounted:function(){
        this.__instance=new RadialProgressChart(this.$el, this.buildOptions());
    },
  methods:{
    buildOptions:function(){
        var settings=this.settings||[];
      var me=this;
      settings.series.forEach(function(itm,indx){
            itm.value=me.values[indx]||0;
      });
      return settings;
    }
  },
  watch:{
    values:function(nv){
        if(!this.__instance)
        return;

        this.__instance.update(nv);
    }
  }
});
```

**Component Template:**

```
<template id="radial-graph">
  <div></div>
</template>
```

Then, in your app, you can use the component something along the lines below

(See the `radial-graph` tag):

**Vue App:**

```
var app=new Vue({
el:"#app",
data:{
 values:[10,20],
 settings:{diameter: 10,series:[{color:"green"},{color:"blue"}]}
},
mounted:function(){
    var me=this;
    setInterval(function(){
    var arr=[];
    me.values.forEach(function(){
        arr.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 5)));
    });
    me.values=arr;
  },2000);
}
});
```

**Vue App Template:**

```
<div id="app">
  Graph Display
  <div>
    <radial-graph v-bind:settings="settings" v-bind:values="values"></radial-graph>
  </div>
</div>
```

A working fiddle is [available here](https://jsfiddle.net/ex15tpz2/1/)

Comment: Thanks man, I will work with tomorrow, then I will let you know about my update .